# Mutate right price in array of objects given object's price and quantiy javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi Guys I'm need your help cause 
Im terrible with math ;D

I'm trying to mutate the price 
of an object in a array but I'm 
not getting it right I know that 
the price should be "price * quantity" 
but every time I run the function it 
keeps multiplying the price here goes the function:

```
  const {
    setCart,
    cart
  } = useCart()

  function handeleCartControl({
    array,
    newProduct,
    statement1,
    statement2
  }: {
    array: ProductType[],
    newProduct: ProductType,
    statement1: boolean,
    statement2: boolean,
  }) {
    if (statement1) {
      return array.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item,
          price: item.price * count
        }
      })
    } else if (statement2) {
      return [...array, newProduct]
    } else return array.filter(item => item.productRef !== newProduct.productRef)
  }

  function handleCart() {
    const newProduct: ProductType = {
      picture: imageSrc,
      title,
      price: price * count,
      productRef,
      quantity: count
    }  
    setCart(prev => handeleCartControl({
      array: prev,
      newProduct,
      statement1: prev.some(item => item.productRef === productRef) && count !== 0,
      statement2: count > 0
    }))
  }
```

if you guys know to to solve it 
please let me know.

Comment: This is not your complete code and it's impossible to tell what is wrong without the rest of it. Where is `count` defined?

Comment: Also, why are you setting `price: price * count,` in `newProduct`?

Comment: the "count" indicates how many of the same product it goes in the "quantity' field of the object. the count var is a variable the changes on a onclick event that icrements or decrements the "count", my logic was that the price sould be the price being sent to in newProduct.price * count, wich matches with the the the quantity field

Comment: @JustinTaddei when I run the first one (statement2) it works as expected than on (statement1) it keeps multiplyng

Comment: @JustinTaddei just updated the full code

Comment: Are you trying to set the `price` property of an object or are you trying to compute a total cost, i.e. price * quantity? If just setting a price value then you shouldn't be multiplying against any quantity value, and if computing a total, well, then this doesn't belong in your state as it's considered derived state, i.e. derived from the price and quantity that ***is*** stored in state.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
          price: newProduct.price
```

I did it right the problem 
was that I was trying to multiply that again ;D